# ARM template for elastic database pool fails

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

I'm having issues trying to deploy an ARM with ElasticPool GeneralPurpose edition.  ihave to tried this in mulitple environment but it keeps failing. I'm using the code below which referenced from the Github repository of starter templates

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "administratorLogin": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The SQL Server administrator login"
      }
    },
    "administratorLoginPassword": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The SQL Server administrator login password."
      }
    },
    "serverName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The SQL Server name."
      }
    },
    "elasticPoolName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Elastic Pool name."
      }
    },
    "edition": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "Standard",
      "allowedValues": [
        "Basic",
        "Standard",
        "Premium",
        "GP_Gen5",
        "BC_Gen5"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Elastic Pool edition."
      }
    },
    "capacity": {
      "type": "int",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Elastic Pool DTU or nomber of vcore."
      }
    },
    "databaseCapacityMin": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue": 0,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Elastic Pool database capacity min."
      }
    },
    "databaseCapacityMax": {
      "type": "int",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The Elastic Pool database capacity max."
      }
    },
    "databasesNames": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        "db1",
        "db2"
      ],
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The SQL Databases names."
      }
    },
    "databaseCollation": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The SQL Database collation."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Location for all resources."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "editionToSkuMap": {
      "Basic": {
        "family": null,
        "name": "BasicPool",
        "tier": "Basic"
      },
      "Standard": {
        "family": null,
        "name": "StandardPool",
        "tier": "Standard"
      },
      "Premium":  {
        "family": null,
        "name": "PremiumPool",
        "tier": "Premium"
      },
      "GP_Gen5": {
        "family": "Gen5",
        "name": "GP_Gen5",
        "tier": "GeneralPurpose"
      },
      "BC_Gen5": {
          "family": "Gen5",
          "name": "BC_Gen5",
          "tier": "BusinessCritical"
      }
    },
    "skuName": "[variables('editionToSkuMap')[parameters('edition')].name]",
    "skuTier": "[variables('editionToSkuMap')[parameters('edition')].tier]",
    "skuFamily": "[variables('editionToSkuMap')[parameters('edition')].family]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
      "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
        "version": "12.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticPools",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
      ],
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/', parameters('elasticPoolName'))]",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[variables('skuName')]",
        "tier": "[variables('skuTier')]",
        "family": "[variables('skuFamily')]",
        "capacity": "[parameters('capacity')]"
      },
      "properties": {
        "perDatabaseSettings": {
        "minCapacity": "[parameters('databaseCapacityMin')]",
        "maxCapacity": "[parameters('databaseCapacityMax')]"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/', parameters('databasesNames')[copyIndex()])]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]",
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools', parameters('serverName'), parameters('elasticPoolName'))]"
      ],
      "sku": {
          "name": "ElasticPool",
          "tier": "[variables('skuTier')]",
          "capacity": 0
      },
      "properties": {
        "collation": "[parameters('databaseCollation')]",
        "elasticPoolId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/elasticpools', parameters('serverName'), parameters('elasticPoolName'))]"
      },
      "copy": {
        "name": "addDatabasesInElasticPool",
        "count": "[length(parameters('databasesNames'))]"
      }
    },
    {
      "apiVersion": "2020-02-02-preview",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
      ],
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/', 'AllowAllWindowsAzureIps')]",
      "properties": {
        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallrules"
    }
  ]
}
```

The deployment fails with this error

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"InvalidTierSkuCombination","message":"The tier 'GeneralPurpose' does not support the sku 'SQLDB_GP_Gen5'."}]}
```

Please what can be issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message explains the cause of the deployment failure

> The tier 'GeneralPurpose' does not support the sku 'SQLDB_GP_Gen5'

The mapping of tier to sku is controlled by the input parameter `edition`, and the `editionToSkuMap` variable map, which indicates to me that the variable map is not correct. You'll likely need to dig into what the valid sku values are for a tier with the az CLI

```
az sql elastic-pool list-editions -l -o table
```

and update the variable mapping, then try to deploy again. It's probably worth [opening an issue on the Azure Quickstart templates repository too](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Please download [this](https://github.com/alberto-morillo/AzureElasticPoolGeneralPurpose) template (template.json & parameters.json) from [GitHub](https://github.com/alberto-morillo/AzureElasticPoolGeneralPurpose) that will allow you to create an Azure SQL Database Elastic Pool - General Purpose with one database included.